# What formal phrase is used when someone started speaking and behaving in a very angry way?

Tags: idiom-requests

If **go off on someone** is informal, what is formal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepted idioms:  one can **boil with anger** or **bristle with rage**  [free dict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/anger)

ps formal or not, idioms are idioms and it seems to me can be used at any time ... well maybe not at a funeral.  But *then again* ...